# Bootstrap accordion (On click of button, all other parts of accordion should be closed and hidden from display)

Tags: accordion, panel, jquery-ui-accordion, bootstrap-accordion

Trying to have an accordion with 4 or 5 main buttons, when one is clicked, others should disappear so that the clicked button should be the only one displayed. When minimized, others should reappear to show entire accordion again.

I'm thinking that some sort of toggle such as this (which I have on another section of the site) may be applicable? Except I should be hiding multiple accordion buttons, instead of just essentially toggling between hiding/displaying two sections:

```
        function myFunction() 
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("text");
            var y = document.getElementById("text2");
            if (x.style.display === "none")
            {
                x.style.display = "block";
                y.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
                y.style.display = "block";
            }
        }
```

This is the code I have currently, with a script that currently just makes sure only one accordion panel is displayed at a time:

```
<style>
p.accordion {
background-color: #eee;
color: #444;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 14px;
width: 60%;
text-align: left;
border: none;
outline: none;
transition: 0.4s;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin: auto;
}
p.accordion.active, p.accordion:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
}
p.accordion:after {
content: '\2795'; 
font-size: 13px;
color: #777;
float: right;
margin-left: 5px;
}
p.accordion.active:after {
content: "\2796"; 
}
/* Style the element that is used for the panel class */
div.panel {
background-color: white;
max-height: 0;
width: 60%;
text-align: left;
overflow: hidden;
transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
opacity: 0;
margin-bottom:10px;
margin: auto;
}
div.panel.show {
padding: 10pt;
opacity: 1;
max-height: 500px;
border: none;
}
</style>
```

```
<p class="accordion">PanelOne</p>
      <div class="panel">
        Lorem Ipsum
      </div>

<p class="accordion">PanelTwo</p>
      <div class="panel">
        Lorem Ipsum II
      </div>

<p class="accordion">PanelThree</p>
      <div class="panel">
        Lorem Ipsum III
      </div>

                <script>
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event)
                    { 
                    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
                    var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
                    for (var i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) 
                    {
                        acc[i].onclick = function() 
                        {
                        var setClasses = !this.classList.contains('active');
                        setClass(acc, 'active', 'remove');
                        setClass(panel, 'show', 'remove');
                        if (setClasses) 
                        {
                            this.classList.toggle("active");
                            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                        }
                        }
                    }
                    function setClass(els, className, fnName) 
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) 
                        {
                        els[i].classList[fnName](className);
                        }
                    }
                    });
                </script>
```

Any hints/fixes would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One of the many possible solutions:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
        var panel = document.getElementsByClassName('panel');
        for (let i = 0; i < acc.length; i += 1) {
            acc[i].onclick = function () {
                this.classList.toggle("active");
                this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
                for (let j = 0; j < acc.length; j += 1) {
                    if (i !== j) {
                        acc[j].style.display = acc[j].style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```